# With express.js how do I configure an upload file directory only for testing?

Tags: express, testing

I have a form with a file upload field. I want to upload the file during a test. Normally the file is placed in the static file folder in the `files` folder. In production the static folder is `build` and in development the static folder is `client` however I want the uploaded files to be saved and served from `tmp/` during testing or, at least, in a directory I can delete after each test. Right now the test and development configurations use the same directory. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I put two dots, `..`, in the file path of the test environment configuration file to move up a directory. It isn't that hacky.

So server/config/environment/test.js becomes:

```
'use strict';

// Set the 'test' environment configuration object
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/simplejobs-test',
    dir: 'client/',
    fileDir: '../tmp/files/',
    sessionSecret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'MEAN'
};
```

while server/config/environment/development.js remains:

```
'use strict';

// Set the 'development' environment configuration object
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/simplejobs-dev',
    dir: 'client/',
    fileDir: 'files/'
    sessionSecret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'MEAN'
};
```